# Microsoft ReportViewer - ASP.NET Session Expired

Tags: reportviewer

This question is related to [Microsoft ReportViewer: Session Expired Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178600/microsoft-reportviewer-session-expired-errors).  Unfortunately, the accepted answer does not solve my issue.  The report viewer in question is running in a farm, with multiple worker processes running in each app pool.  Session mode is SQL.  I have implemented IReportServerConnection.

The problem I have is that the session is coming back expired immediately.  I can duplicate this on a single box, so I assume this is related to the multiple worker processes.  I am using RDL files and I don't think the ReportViewer even needs session enabled.  So my questions is: How do I get rid of this error?  If it is by disabling session for reportviewer, how do I do that?  I thought that implementing IReportServerConnection would handle that.  The documentation seems sparse.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the exception and stack trace:

Message: ASP.NET session has expired
Process Name: Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms
Type: Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.AspNetSessionExpiredException
StackTrace: at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataOperation..ctor()     at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.GetHandler(String operationType)     at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting AsyncRendering to False.  I had read this solution, but hoped to find an alternative.  There may be other options for web gardens/farms, but this is the only one I could come up with in the limited time I had to look.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252090%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: AsyncRendering set to false did not resolve the issue for me.  I am using the latest version of ReportViewer used in VS2013.  I can't believe this bug has not been fixed yet.  (I am considering abandoning ReportViewer web control and perhaps redirect user directly to SSRS Server report URL.)

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  I remember having further issues with ReportViewer.  It was very disappointing.